# Why "v-if" directive does not show hidden element when data is changed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

i'm using Vue 2. With first render element is hidden, when i click on .mobile-trigger i can see in Vue-DevTools how variable "mobileMenuIsOpen" is changed to true, but .overlay is still not exist in DOM.

```
.mobile-trigger(@click='mobileMenuIsOpen = true')

.overlay(v-if='mobileMenuIsOpen')
```

...

```
  data () {
    return {
      mobileMenuIsOpen: false
    }
  }
```

Comment: I am also new to vue.js but are you trying to add a click event on a CSS selector? Why don't you add it directly to the element in your HTML?

Comment: Please add more code about what you're doing exactly here, your html as well

Comment: Cristy, no i'm not. This is [Pug(Jade)](https://github.com/pugjs). I'm forgot to explain that, sorry.

Comment: Chiko, just found the solution thanks to you! see answer below

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone, who read this and leave comment in this question.
I'm forgot to explain, i'm using Pug(Jade)-preprocessor in this the code. 
And i have not added enought code to give you help me.

So the problem was in the "v-once" directive which i put into component's root-element.